# How do I keep my old saves for Batman Arkham Asylum?

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-asylum

Due to Microsoft shutting down Games for Windows Live (I wish they did it right after they launched and spared everybody the headache), Batman Arkham Asylum has been [retooled for Steamworks](http://steamcommunity.com/games/200260/announcements/detail/1909817119598626547). This is great, but Batman Arkham Asylum no longer recognizes my save. How can I take my old saves into the bright new era of Steam DRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start a new game and make sure the game autosaves (the first autosave is 2 skipped cutscenes into the game); quit the game.
2. Find your old save file at `C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\Square Enix\Batman Arkham Asylum GOTY\SaveData\########`, where xxxxxxxx is your Windows login and ######## is a bunch of random characters, and copy it somewhere.
3. Download [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) or use a different hex editor of your choice.
4. Open the copied file with XVI32.
5. In the menu, do `Address -> Go to...`, make sure the mode is set to hexadecimal, enter $183 in the input box and hit OK.
6. In the menu, do `Edit -> Delete to cursor`.
7. Save the edited file.
8. Go to your Steam folder, then navigate to `userdata\######\35140\remote` for the GOTY edition or `userdata\######\35019\remote` for the regular edition, where ###### is your Steam ID.
9. Replace the `save0.sgd` file with the edited save.
10. Start the game.